# Awful loading text being displayed when seeing upvotes and downvotes

Tags: bug

When trying to see the upvotes and downvotes details of a post (not just the sum of them) I noticed that a horrible `0loading...` text appears for less than a second and is then replaced by the actual votes. I managed to take a screenshot.

[image]

Even the text of the question is pushed to the right. I could also reproduce this behaviour by clearing the cache of the browser, refreshing the page and finally trying to see the detail again.

NOTE: I'm using FireFox 11.0

Comment: Why is the bottom of your image garbled? Have you tried to run the browser in safe mode?

Comment: this also happened to me for a second. It is not that annoying but it would be good to have fixed

Comment: @TomWijsman Noticed that. Must be some repainting issue with FF. Anyway, it shouldn't be related to the question itself